# Need equivalent Linq of given SQL query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Below is My SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE 
MyColomn = 
(
    SELECT Max(MyColomn) FROM MyTable
    WHERE MyColomn <= @input 
) 
or 
MyColomn = 
(
     SELECT min(MyColomn) FROM MyTable
     WHERE MyColomn >= @input
)
```

Can some one help me to get `LINQ` equivalent query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `linq` is like this:

```
DbContext.MyTable.Where(u =>

    u.MyColomn == DbContext.MyTable.Where(t => t.MyColomn <= @input)
        .Max(t => t.MyColomn) ||
    u.MyColomn == DbContext.MyTable.Where(t => t.MyColomn >= @input)
        .Min(t => t.MyColomn)

).ToList();
```